# php if elseif statement select wrong variable every time

Tags: php, if-statement

Hi i got this statement for a query to post the specific data after checking for the right "postnummer".

```
if($_POST['postnummer'] == "7900" or "7950" or "7960") {
    $region = "Nordjylland";
    }
    elseif ($_POST['postnummer'] == "8654" or "8660" or "8680" or "8700") {
        $region = "Midtjylland";
    }
```

but the value posted is "Nordjylland" every time ?

Comment: PHP is not English. `or "7950"` is always `true`, because the expression `"7950"` is always `true`.

Comment: It would be advisable to **learn the language** before asking trivial questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write

```
if($_POST['postnummer'] == "7900" || $_POST['postnummer'] == "7950" || $_POST['postnummer'] == "7960") {
    $region = "Nordjylland";
}
elseif ($_POST['postnummer'] == "8654" || $_POST['postnummer'] == "8660" || $_POST['postnummer'] == "8680" || $_POST['postnummer'] == "8700") {
        $region = "Midtjylland";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use arrays

```
$nordjyllandRegions = array("7900","7950","7960");
$midtjyllandRegions = array("8654","8660","8680","8700");

$zipcode = $_POST['postnummer'];

if(in_array($zipcode, $nordjyllandRegions)) {
  $region = "Nordjylland";
}
elseif (in_array($zipcode, $midtjyllandRegions)) {
  $region = "Midtjylland";
}
```

Comment: I like this answer. Nice and clean.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the switch statement, which is than easier to read:

```
switch ($_POST['postnummer']) {
    case "7900":
    case "7950":
    case "7960":
        $region = "Nordjylland";
        break;
    case "8654":
    case "8660":
    case "8680":
    case "8700":
        $region = "Midtjylland";
        break;
    default:
        $region = "no match";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$postNummer = (int) $_POST['postnummer'];    
if( in_array( $postNummer, array( 7900, 7950, 7960 ) ) )
{
  $region = "Nordjylland";
}
elseif( in_array( $postNummer, array( 8654, 8660, 8680, 8700 ) ) )
{
  $region = "Midtjylland";
}
```

or

```
$postNummer = (int) $_POST['postnummer']; 
switch( $postNummer )
{
  case 7900:
  case 7950:
  case 7960:
    $region = "Nordjylland";
    break;

  case 8654:
  case 8660:
  case 8680:
  case 8700:
    $region = "Midtjylland";
    break;
}
```